# Table : set cells exact size

Tags: tables, cell, sticky-labels

I'd like to make a tex document that would fit pre-cut sticking labels sheets.

I set the margins with the `geometry` package. I now want to create a table that would hold the values I have to print on labels, so I must set the exact same width and height for each cell.

The sticking labels sheet is 5 * 13 labels, with 1cm margin top, bottom, left and right.

I can't figure out how to set those cells' size. Would you please accept to help me ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Rather than reinvent the wheel, perhaps the [`labels`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/labels?lang=en) package can do what you want. (Already part of TeXLive and MikTeX).

Comment: BTW, I forgot to say that all labels are different from each other ...

Comment: The package can handle a file of names + addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the `labels` package, but it might just be the ticket. If you prefer a regular table syntax, here is one way to do it. We use the `tikz` package to format each label, and the `collcell` package to apply the `tikz` macro automatically to each table cell.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,collcell,array,calc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

% some padding for the text inside each label
\newlength{\nodepadding}
\setlength{\nodepadding}{8pt}

% the tikz wrapper command that formats each label
% contains some stuff that you may not want - just 
% for illustrating that it is easy enough in case you do
\newcommand{\mycell}[1]{%
  \tikz{%
    \node[
      fill=yellow,
      draw,                                      % draw border
      align=left,                                % left-align text
      outer sep=0pt,                             % no padding on the outside 
      inner sep=\nodepadding,                    % apply inner padding
      minimum height=\textheight/13,             % scale height to page
      text width=\textwidth/5-2\nodepadding,     % scale width to page
      rounded corners=2pt] {#1}}}                % round corners with given radius

% declare a column type that applies the tikz wrapper macro to each cell
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\mycell}p{\textwidth/5}<{\endcollectcell}}

% clobber any spurious white space that might get in the way
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\pagestyle{empty}  % no page number

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}LLLLL@{}}
Some & stuff    & or    & other & tripe \\
yet  & another  & label & to    & print \\
some long text that hopefully wraps & some text\newline with\newline manual line breaks & b & c & d \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This gives

[image]